# Overlay with a DIV dynamic data in table format via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I'm trying to display data in a table format. The table however needs to be dynamic, so it will accommodate  more or less rows, depending on the data list shown. I would love to do it with Raphael.js, so I can mess with effects, but plain Jane is good enough now.  An example with two rows and two columns will suffice.

Now, I know how to create a static table in HTML inside a div, but I need this to overlay an existing page with JavaScript.

All I was able to do so far is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TESTING CODE</title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function routeIt (kontent, zPath) {
        if (zPath == 'Meeting') { 
            var ta1 = document.createElement('div');
            ta1.setAttribute("name","travel");
            ta1.setAttribute("id","mobile");
            ta1.setAttribute("style","position:float");
            ta1.setAttribute("id","mobile");
            ta1.setAttribute("width","600");
            ta1.setAttribute("height","100");
            ta1.setAttribute("left","120");
            ta1.setAttribute("top","320");
            document.getElementById.('mobile').innerHTML = 'This venerable day of march the 42nd I pledge to uphold the traditions of all the welders...';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="linqs"  href="javascript:routeIt('Hello','Meeting')   "><span title="Make comments about the Meeting...">Meetings</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="linqs"  href="javascript:routeIt('Tzigane','Resolution')"><span title="Make comments about your Portfolio...">Portfolio</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="linqs2" href="javascript:routeIt('Kratt','SendEmail') "><span title="Emails from ...">Email</span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

The last line does not work and the DIV or the contents do not show up... but it does not err in creating the DIV.  So, I'm not even able to get the DIV to come up!

The data lists are coming in as follows:

```
zList1 = [['zebra','24'],['cat','153'],['paycheck','$123.56']]
zList2 = [['Wine','gloogloo'],['cereal','bowl'],['garage','three cars']]
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Dennis

Comment: Did you add(append) the text area to the page.
My thought is to append the Element to the page, here from your snippet the statement is missing. Cheers Arun

Comment: What do you mean append?  I am a neophyte i JavaScript!  CreateElement requires an append?  Since when?

Comment: document.getElementById(Your_Target_Element_Should_be_here).appendChild(ta1);  You did create a new div, and customized with properties but just forgot to add that to the page

Comment: Viva Amerika!  I had no clue...  Now, I'm adding this to the body.  So, should it be this way?
document.getElementById('body').appendChild(ta1);

Comment: It may be the child of any other parent component, For your Better Understand <body .......> <div id= "ta1">......</div>......</body> This is how the page will be if you append the div element to the body. Here What i did is document.getElementById("bodyId").appendChild(ta1); Hope You can get it to work .

Comment: Yeah You are correct. Glad if i spot a light on your problem.

Comment: No, that does not work.  The ".appendChild(ta1)" portion is not working, for some reason...

Comment: Ok, it made me feel worry, well still we have control. Do you get any error while opening the page in Bowser, (Hope you do use developer tools of corresponding browser you using). or do you get the alert boxes while clicking the link "messages" , if not then probably your code have issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is The Bug Fixed code: Try and post the comment,


    function routeIt (kontent, zPath) {
        if (zPath == 'Meeting') { 
            var ta1 = document.createElement('div');
            ta1.setAttribute("name","travel");
            ta1.setAttribute("id","mobile");
            ta1.setAttribute("style","position:float");
            ta1.setAttribute("id","mobile");
            ta1.setAttribute("width","600");
            ta1.setAttribute("height","100");
            ta1.setAttribute("left","120");
            ta1.setAttribute("top","320");
            document.getElementById("bodyID").appendChild(ta1);
            document.getElementById.('mobile').innerHTML = 'This venerable day of march the 42nd I pledge to uphold the traditions of all the welders...';
}
    }


add id="bodyID" to the the body tag definition.

Cheers, Arun
```